# Objective-C: headerdoc2html doesn't generate the documentation for protocol

Tags: objective-c, documentation, header-files

I tried to generate documentations by headerdoc2html command.
But headerdoc only generates toc.html. There is not index.html for the protocol.
Something wrong?

I used following header file and command.

```
/*!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  @header Dummy.h                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  hoge                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


/*!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  @class Foo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  asdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
@interface Foo : NSObject                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

/*!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  @abstract xxx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
- (void)xxx;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

@end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

/*!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  @protocol BarDelegate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
@protocol BarDelegate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

/*!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  @abstract Sent after something                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
- (void)didSomething:(Foo *)foo;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
@end
```

--

```
$ headerdoc2html *.h -o doc
```

The result was,

```
$ find doc
doc
doc/Dummy_h
doc/Dummy_h/Classes
doc/Dummy_h/Classes/Foo
doc/Dummy_h/Classes/Foo/index.html
doc/Dummy_h/Classes/Foo/toc.html
doc/Dummy_h/index.html
doc/Dummy_h/Protocols
doc/Dummy_h/Protocols/BarDelegate
doc/Dummy_h/Protocols/BarDelegate/toc.html
doc/Dummy_h/toc.html
```

Comment: Using exactly that invocation with exactly that header file works for me (with Xcode 4.4.1's `headerdoc2html`). Try using the `-d` flag for additional debugging information to see how it's parsing the header for you.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem of older version of header2html. I updated Xcode's Command Line Tools and fixed the problem. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your code is perfect but when it come for commad which are wrong.  Their are four steps to create the headerDoc.

Step 1 : Go to the directory where your project is located (In stead of the header file what you did).

`$ cd <Your_Project_Directory>`

Step 2 : Now create HTML DOC files of your project's all controller and create a directory to where you will going to generate your HTML DOC file.

`<Your_Project_Directory> $ headerdoc2html -o <DIR_PATH_TO_CREATE_YOUR_DOC>  <PROJECT_NAME>`

Step 3 : Now you will see their are stuff created in the directory path where you are created your doc file. Don't think to much about that We will see it later. Now go to the directory where you created your HTML files

`<Your_Project_Directory> $ cd <DIR_PATH_TO_CREATE_YOUR_DOC>`

Step 4 : Their are so many files right now in the your directory and all them are separated with each other so to make it together and create link with each other you have to apply the last command.

`gatherheaderdoc ..`

Here last '..'(Two dots) will create "masterTOC.HTML" file to the parent file. Now you can open this and test your project.